# How do I get the drop down section hidden on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that slides down once a button is clicked. This function is working correctly, but currently the drop down section is already toggled on page load. How do I get it to be hidden until the button is clicked?

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/maddiwu/xe6xtfqh/

```css
.slide {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: 100vw;
    /* approximate max height */
    width:100%;
    /*height: 45vw;*/
    background:#2e2e2e;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
.slide.closed {
    max-height: 0;
}
.banner7 {
    width:80%;
    background:#d8d8d8;
    margin-top:1.5vw;
    padding-top:2vw;
}
.banner8 {
    width:80%;
    background:#2e2e2e;
    margin-top:1vw;
    margin-left:10%;
    padding-top:2vw;
}
```

```html
<center>
    <div class="banner7" style="margin-bottom:0vw;margin-top:2vw;">
         <h1 style="color:#B40404;font-size:2.5vw;margin:1.5vw;font-family:Futura;">MAIN SECTION</h1>

        <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:back;margin-left:5vw; margin-right:5vw; text-align:center; margin-top:-1vw;margin-bottom:3vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
        <table style="width:95%; margin-left:2%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="background:white;width:21vw;margin-top:0vw;margin-bottom:2vw;padding:1vw;">
                         <h1 style="color:#b40404;font-size:1.5vw;font-family:Futura; text-align:center;margin-top:1vw;">SUB SECTION ONE</h1>

                        <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:#2e2e2e; text-align:center; margin-top:1vw;margin-bottom:1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
                        <center>
                            <img src="images/button.png" style="width:35%;height:3vw;margin-top:1vw; margin-bottom:1vw;" onmouseover="this.src='images/button-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/button.png'" onload="closed" onclick="document.getElementById('slide').classList.toggle('closed');" />
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background:white;width:21vw;margin-top:0vw;margin-bottom:2vw;padding:1vw;">
                         <h1 style="color:#b40404;font-size:1.5vw;font-family:Futura; text-align:center;margin-top:1vw;">SUB SECTION TWO</h1>

                        <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:#2e2e2e; text-align:center; margin-top:1vw;margin-bottom:1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
                        <center>
                            <img src="images/button.png" style="width:35%;height:3vw;margin-top:1vw; margin-bottom:1vw;" onmouseover="this.src='images/button-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/button.png'" onclick="document.getElementById('slide').classList.toggle('closed');" />
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background:white;width:21vw;margin-top:0vw;margin-bottom:2vw;padding:1vw;">
                         <h1 style="color:#b40404;font-size:1.5vw;font-family:Futura; text-align:center;margin-top:1vw;">SUB SECTION THREE</h1>

                        <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:#2e2e2e; text-align:center; margin-top:1vw;margin-bottom:1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
                        <center>
                            <img src="images/button.png" style="width:35%;height:3vw;margin-top:1vw; margin-bottom:1vw;" onmouseover="this.src='images/button-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/button.png'" onclick="document.getElementById('slide').classList.toggle('closed');" />
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</center>
<div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide">
        <div style="width:100%; background:#2e2e2e; padding:1vw; text-align:center;">
            <table style="width:80%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <iframe style="margin-left:20%;width:45vw;height:30vw;" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/P7mS83pOPso" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center>
                             <h1 style="color:#d8d8d8;font-size:2.5vw;font-family:Futura; text-align:center;margin-top:0vw;margin-left:20vw;">DROP SECTION</h1>

                            <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:white;margin-left:11vw;margin-right:-8vw; text-align:center; margin-top:1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </center>
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%; background:#d8d8d8; padding:1vw; text-align:center;">
            <center>
                <center>
                     <h1 style="color:#b40404;font-size:2.5vw;font-family:Futura; text-align:center;margin-top:2vw;">DROP SECTION</h1>

                    <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:#2e2e2e;margin-right:10vw;margin-left:10vw; text-align:center; margin-top:-1vw;margin-bottom:2vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
                </center>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: **display:none; visibility:hidden; opacity:0; z-index:-1;** pick any.

Answer (score 3):

Have your default HTML start out with `<div class="slide closed" id="slide">` . . . if the toggle code is working (as you mentioned) and based on the CSS definitions, having the `closed` class in place by default should put it in the closed state when the page loads.